# VS-Studio 2015: How to automatically add a new class to Source Control on Check-In

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We often "forget" to add newly created class files before checkin.

We are struggeling to find a way to automatically add new classes (or other project files which contain source code).

Any hints out there? Binding the solution to source control does not seem to help.

thx in advance

Comment: It sounds like you have an issue with how you are binding your solutions / projects to TFS. If you right click on a project and select "Add" "New item" then Visual Studio should pend a change in TFS automatically

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, TFS will not auto scan the workspace folder to check if there have new files be added, you will **have to add the new files in source control manually.**

Please refer this [Add Files to Version Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181374(v=vs.100).aspx) from MSDN, it tells you how to use VS to add a file that is not in a solution to version control.

And also you can use **tfs command** to achieve it. From a VS 2015 command prompt, navigate to the root directory and run

```
tf add *.<file extension> /recursive
```

Moreover, after you installed [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) (*the version of it must match to VS version*) on your local machine, you also can right-click on workspace folder(team project or project folder) and select  **Team Foundation Server>>Add…** to add files. 
[image]